# Using sed to cut a string starting with n spaces and ending with n spaces

Tags: text-processing, sed

How to use `sed` to cut text starting with x spaces and ending with y spaces?

For instance This is my string:

```
 kkk 111 fff      aaabbb 5d98 ccc         mmmppp 9369d
```

and I want to get this output:

```
 aaabbb 5d98 ccc
```

(the number of spaces is not known)

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to print every word in the file that has the same number of spaces on either side?

Comment: seems like an XYproblem... you actually want the title (with possibly several words), am i right?

Comment: @Qlivier Dulac: Yes you're right the title can have several words I forgot to specify this. I'm editing my question so it reflects this.

Comment: Could you add multiple examples of the actual lines you want to extract the title from? If you can, include the most difficult ones as well as several standard ones. That will make your actual requirements a lot clearer, which will make it easier to give you a useful answer. :-) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my question so it reflects the most accurate use case. String: `kkk 111 fff      aaabbb 5d98 ccc         mmmppp 9369d`, result: `aaabbb 5d98 ccc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We told about some text staring with unknown quantity of spaces so

```
sed 's/.* \{2,\}\([[:alnum:]].*\) \{2,\}.*/\1/'
```

or with -r (-E)

```
sed -E 's/.* {2,}([[:alnum:]].*) {2,}.*/\1/'
```

seems to enough but `grep` is better in the case

```
grep -Po ' {2,}\K[[:alnum:]].*(?= {2,})'
```

And not so strong (just with two whitespaces) but correct too:

```
sed -E 's/.*  (\w.*)  .*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm sorry no one worked for me.. I think because of the use case I gave.. Actually even the title contains spaces: `01      Lorem Ipsum      Chapter 01`

Comment: @pr.nizar This is because you use `tabs` instead `spaces` so `sed -E 's/.*\t(.+)\t.*/\1/'` will help you

Comment: No actually I used 6 `spaces` before and after the title but `echo '01      Lorem Ipsum      Chapter      01' | sed 's/.* \{2,\}\([[:alnum:] ]\{2,\}\) \{2,\}.*/\1/'` gives nothing as output. Same thing for the 2nd and 4th. The 3rd gave me `Lorem Ipsum      Chapter`.

Comment: No, let's say alfanum of any length. The only delimeter are n `spaces` before and after the title. Let's say this string: `kkk 111 fff      aaabbb 5d98 ccc         mmmppp 9369d`; I want to get `aaabbb 5d98 ccc` as result. I'm sorry I'm a total noob at RegEx.

Comment: Actually the amount of `spaces` is greater than one `space` but it's random n `spaces`.

Comment: @pr.nizar Be sure that spaces 2 or more `sed -E 's/.* {2,}(\w.+\w) {2,}.*/\1/'`

Comment: Yep that is the correct answer! You did it! Thank you very much! Can you edit your answer so I tick it as the correct answer?

Comment: @pr.nizar Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-r` option for extended regular expression where number of characters can be specified inside `{}`, so the following will print all *words* surrounded by 6 spaces:

```
sed -r 's/.* {6}(\w*) {6}.*/\1/'
```

In case if the *title* has spaces too, the better choice would be

```
sed -r 's/.* {6}(.*) {6}.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm sorry this didn't work for me.. I think because of the use case I gave.. Actually even the title contains spaces: `01      Lorem Ipsum      Chapter 01`

Comment: @pr.nizar try with `sed -r 's/.* {6}(.*) {6}.*/\1/'`. This **must** work, however it can match more instances than you may want to (for example it includes additional spaces in the pattern in case if more then 6 spaces surrounding the title).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I've borrowed the `-r` flag (enables extended regex syntax) from jimmij to cure backlashitis.**

The following works, under the following conditions:

- you are willing to say that the field separator is at least *n* spaces, e.g. 3
- the contents of the field of interest do not include a space anywhere.

In that case, this regex works:

```
    echo ' 01      Title      Chapter 01' |
    sed -r 's/^.* {3,}([^ ]+) {3,}.*$/\1/'
```

Or, in case you like your backslashes, this is what this looks like in non-extended regex syntax:

```
    echo ' 01      Title      Chapter 01' |
    sed 's/^.* \{3,\}\([^ ]\+\) \{3,\}.*$/\1/'
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
^        start of line
.*       any number of characters at the start of the line
 {3,}    at least 3 spaces
([^ ]+)  1 or more non-space characters (capture this group as \1)
 {3,}    at least 3 spaces
.*       anything on the rest of the line
$        end of the line. Not needed, because of the .*, but nicely explicit.
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm sorry this didn't work for me.. I think because of the use case I gave.. Actually even the title contains spaces: `01      Lorem Ipsum      Chapter 01` ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the same number of spaces on either side:

```
$ sed -r 's/(^|.*[^[:space:]])([[:space:]]+)([^[:space:]]+)\2([^[:space:]].*|$)/\3/g' <<<"01      Title      Chapter 01"
Title
```

(I used the character class instead of just , with just a space, the expression should be considerably shorter: `sed -r 's/(^|.*[^ ])( +)([^ ]+)\2([^ ].*|$)/\3/g'`).

By using the backreference within LHS, we ensure that the same number of spaces are present on both sides.

Comment: Thank you but I'm sorry it worked partially.. I think because of the use case I gave.. Actually even the title contains spaces: `01      Lorem Ipsum      Chapter 01`.. For this I get only `Lorem`..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to catch the title ?

here us a way to catch things by getting rid of the first word,  and the last 2 words, and displaying the rest (spaces included) :

```
awk '{ $1=""; $(NF-1)="" ; $NF="" ; print $0}'
```

Or even better: get rid of first element, and discard last 2, and also the extra spaces ( changing a $n, or NF, forces a redraw of $0 on most awk implementation):

```
awk '{ shift ; NF=(NF-2); print $0}'
```

example

```
$   echo   ' 01      Title is   here!     Chapter 01' | awk '{ shift ; NF=(NF-2); print $0}'

 Title is here!
```

The advantage of awk is that it is easy to add tests (is $1 an integer?  is $(NF-1) "Chapter" ? etc)

Comment: Thank you but this outputs `01 Title is here!` and not `Title is here!`

Comment: @pr.nizar : then add a `$2=""` or, better, a `shift`. and now with the modified example, this solution is not valid anymore unless you know how many items to discard