# How to use space seperated string as variable value in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I am creating a basic shell script to manipulate a database as a college assignment. However, How many times I try, I can't get the sed command fully  correct. The functionality where sed is to be used is this:

`$name` is the variable. User will supply the name via the terminal. This name will be looked up in the database and will be deleted if present.

The command I used is this:

```
sed -i /$name/d <filename>
```

However, this command only works if the entered value contains no space.

I tried out my solution by using what I could salvage from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178905/using-sed-to-cut-a-string-starting-with-n-spaces-and-ending-with-n-spaces)
such as `sed -i '/$name/d' <filename>`

However, to no avail. How to go about this?

Comment: Adding quotes somehow doesn't work

Comment: Really? Show me.

Comment: Err.... would drive link do?

Comment: lol, not very big. It's a tiny college assignment with the file containing only few entries. The columns are:

Name                   designation                       department

Comment: Yay!! you're an angel jesse :D

Comment: Note that building a database that you manipulate with `sed` is _extremely fragile_. To take an example, what's stopping a user from deleting _everything_ by entering `.` into the value of that variable? How would you prevent disclosing the contents of it when someone enters a value that contains actual `sed` _code_?

Comment: In this particular case, you could get away with a single set of double quotes: `sed -i "/$name/d" <filename>"` but there are other cases where you have to mix quotes in order to get the shell to do what you want.

Comment: @Kusalananda Who uses sed to create and edit databases??? We have SQL and the likes. I am doing this shitty thing just to get 10 marks for completing my assignment ;)

Comment: Err. Can we use regex to simply replace two pairs of words with different text in between?